# Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sbService';nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to implement basic CRUD Operation on the Spring boot application, but I face bean error. My side is checking all the possibilities but not getting any solution please help me.

Controller Class:

```
@RestController
public class MyTestSampleData {
@Autowired(required=true)
SBService sbService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/Product",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<SamplePojo> getProductList() {
     List<SamplePojo> inputData = new ArrayList();
    try {
        inputData = sbService.getProductNames();
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
    return inputData;
    
}
}
```

Repository Class :

```
package com.ganesh.mytestsample;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

 @Repository
  public interface productRepo extends CrudRepository<SamplePojo, Integer>{


   }
```

POJO CLASS:

```
package com.ganesh.mytestsample;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
@Entity
public class SamplePojo {
@Id
private int id;
private String productName;

public SamplePojo(){
    
}
public SamplePojo(int id, String productName) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.productName = productName;
}
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getProductName() {
    return productName;
}
public void setProductName(String productName) {
    this.productName = productName;
}

}
```

Please, anybody, help me with any functionalities or annotation missing in this code

Service Class:

```
package com.ganesh.mytestsample;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class SBService {

@Autowired(required=true)
productRepo prdRep;

public List<SamplePojo> getProductNames(){
    
    List<SamplePojo> li = new ArrayList();
            
    prdRep.findAll().forEach(prd ->li.add(prd));
    
    return li;
    
    
}
}
```

POM.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema- 
  instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.5</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.ganesh.st</groupId>
<artifactId>FamilyMembers</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>FamilyMembers</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>    
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>    
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>        
    </dependency>  
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Application Properties:

```
server.port=7080
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sb
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect

spring.jpa.database = MYSQL
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
logging.level.root=WARN
```

Error Log:

```
ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception 
encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error 
creating bean with name 'myTestSampleData': Unsatisfied dependency expressed 
through field 'sbService'; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error 
creating bean with name 'SBService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through 
field 'prdRep'; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No 
qualifying bean of type 'com.ganesh.mytestsample.ProductRepo' available: 
expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency 
annotations: 
{@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
            2021-05-05 12:00:55.238 ERROR 12864 --- [           main] 
o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

            ***************************
            APPLICATION FAILED TO START
            ***************************

            Description:

            Field prdRep in com.ganesh.mytestsample.SBService required a bean 
  of type 'com.ganesh.mytestsample.ProductRepo' that could not be found.

            The injection point has the following annotations:
                - 
  @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


            Action:

            Consider defining a bean of type 'com.ganesh.mytestsample.ProductRepo' in your configuration.
```

Comment: Can you please share the complete error log ?

Comment: ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'myTestSampleData': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sbService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'SBService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'prdRep';

Comment: ***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field prdRep in com.ganesh.mytestsample.SBService required a bean of type 'com.ganesh.mytestsample.ProductRepo' that could not be found.

Comment: Have u added @EnableJpaRepositories over a config file ?